# how show object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

> Blockquote

i have this object

```
Object {elementId: "#ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateUserWizard1_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName", elementMessage: "_userName"}
Object {elementId: "#ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateUserWizard1_CreateUserStepContainer_Password", elementMessage: "_password"}
```

i want when element cliecked check id, if id equal "ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateUserWizard1_CreateUserStepContainer_UserName"

alert("_userName")

and if equal
"ContentPlaceHolder1_CreateUserWizard1_CreateUserStepContainer_Password"

alert("_password")

how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
function addClick(obj) {
  var $this = $(obj.elementId);
  $this.on('click', function (event) {
    alert(obj.elementMessage);
    event.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

And then use this function for your different object:

```
addClick(yourObject);
```